# How to get random records from Strapi v4 ? (I answered this question)

Tags: node.js, next.js, content-management-system, strapi

Strapi doesn't have any endpoint to get random data for this purpose you should write some custom code for your endpoint

> 1. custom route for that endpoint you want

[image]

```
// path: ./src/api/[your-endpiont]/routes/[custom-route].js

module.exports = {
  "routes": [
    {
      "method": "GET",
      "path": "/[your-endpiont]/random", // you can define everything you want for url endpoint
      "handler": "[your-endpiont].random", // random is defined as a method
      "config": {
        "policies": []
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

now you have to run `yarn develop` or npm ... to display a random method in your strapi panel
[image]
Save this setting and retry to reach the random endpoint.

> 2. create a function as a service for getting random data in your endpoint API services.

```
// path: ./src/api/[your-endpiont]/services/[your-endpiont].js

'use strict';

/**
 * news-list service.
 */

const { createCoreService } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreService('api::news-list.news-list', ({ strapi }) => ({
    async serviceGetRandom({ locale, id_nin }) { // these parametrs come from query

        function getRandomElementsFromArray(array, numberOfRandomElementsToExtract = 1) {

            const elements = [];

            function getRandomElement(arr) {
                if (elements.length < numberOfRandomElementsToExtract) {
                    const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)
                    const element = arr.splice(index, 1)[0];

                    elements.push(element)

                    return getRandomElement(arr)
                } else {
                    return elements
                }
            }

            return getRandomElement([...array])
        }

        const newsListArray = await strapi
            .db
            .query("api::news-list.news-list")
            .findMany({
                where: {
                    locale: locale, // if you have multi-language data
                    $not: {
                        id: id_nin, // depend on where this endpoint API use
                    },
                    publishedAt: {
                        $notNull: true,
                    },
                },
                sort: [{ datetime: 'asc' }],
                limit: 10,
                populate: {
                    content: {
                        populate: {
                            thumbnail: true,
                        },
                    },
                },
                //? filter object throws an error when you used populate object, everything you want to filter properly best write into where{}
                // filters: {
                //     publishedAt: {
                //         $notNull: true,
                //     },
                //     locale: locale
                // }

            })

        if (!newsListArray.length) {
            return null
        }

        return getRandomElementsFromArray(newsListArray, 2)
         
    }
}));
```

**explain code:**

Strapi provides a Query Engine API to interact with the database layer at a lower level

```
strapi.db.query("api::news-list.news-list").findMany({})
```

The Query Engine allows operations on database entries,
I wrote this for my purpose probably you should change based on what you needed

```
{
                where: {
                    locale: locale,
                    $not: {
                        id: id_nin
                    },
                    publishedAt: {
                        $notNull: true,
                    },
                },
                sort: [{ datetime: 'asc' }],
                limit: 10,
                populate: {
                    content: {
                        populate: {
                            thumbnail: true,
                        },
                    },
                }

}
```

when you get data from your query, passed it to that function `getRandomElementsFromArray(newsListArray, 2)` to get some random item (how many random items do you want ? pass the second parameter)
At least if your array is null return null otherwise return data

> 3. create the controller

Controllers are JavaScript files that contain a set of methods, called actions, reached by the client according to the requested route so we going to call our services in this section

```
// path: ./src/api/[your-endpoint]/controllers/[your-endpoint].js
'use strict';

/**
 *  news-list controller
 */

const { createCoreController } = require('@strapi/strapi').factories;

module.exports = createCoreController('api::news-list.news-list', ({ strapi }) => ({
    async random(ctx) { // name of this methods related to something we define in route  ("handler": "[your-endpiont].random",)
        
        const entity = await strapi.service('api::news-list.news-list').serviceGetRandom(ctx.query) // call our services, you can send all query you get from url endpoint (notice that you should write your endpoint api in strapi.service("your-endpoint"))
        const sanitizedEntity = await this.sanitizeOutput(entity, ctx);

        return this.transformResponse(sanitizedEntity);
        // console.log(entity);
    }
}));
```

I call this endpoint in my project nextjs & stapi cms

```
export const getRandomNewsItem = (id, locale) => {
  return API
    .get(`/news-list/random?locale=${locale}&id_nin=${id}`)
    .then(res => res.data);
};
```

That's it, I'll hope you all get what to do

all resources you need

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/routes.html#creating-custom-routers

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/services.html#implementation

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/development/backend-customization/controllers.html#adding-a-new-controller

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/query-engine-api.html

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/query-engine/filtering.html#and

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/entity-service/order-pagination.html#ordering

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/entity-service/order-pagination.html#ordering

https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/query-engine/populating.html